# recursively add integers from 1^2 to n^2

Tags: java, recursion

i'm having some trouble recursively adding integers in java from 1^2 to n^2.
I want to be able to recursively do this in the recurvMath method but all i'm getting is an infinite loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab9Math {

int count = 0;
static double squareSum = 0;


public static void main(String[] args){

    int n = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the value you want n to be: ");
    n = scan.nextInt();

    Lab9Math est = new Lab9Math();
    squareSum = est.recurvMath(n);
    System.out.println("Sum is: "+squareSum);
}

public int recurvMath(int n){

    System.out.println("N:" +n);
        if(n == 0){
            return 0; 
        }//end if
        if (n == 1){
            return 1;
        }//end if
        if (n > 1){
            return (recurvMath((int) ((int) n+Math.pow(n, 2))));
        }//end if
        return 0;
    }//end method       
}//end class
```

I'm not fully grasping the nature of defining this recursively, as i know that i can get to here:

```
return (int) (Math.pow(n, 2));
```

but i can't incorporate the calling of the recurvMath method correctly in order for it to work.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: To make it a sum, maybe you should be adding two or more things together?

Comment: Why do you want to do this recursively? `int s=0;for(int i=1;i<n*n;i++) s+=i;`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i'm trying to understand recursion in java. What better way then to try programming it!

Comment: Important sidenote: assuming that `n` is non-negative, the last `return 0;` at the end of `recurvMath()` is unreachable. Instead, change the ifs in that function to `if - else if - else`. Also, you should check and throw an exception if `n` is less than 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, when trying to solve recursive problems, it helps to try to work them out in your head before programming them.

You want to sum all integers from 1<sup>2</sup> to n<sup>2</sup>. The first thing we need to do is express this in a way that lends itself to recursion. Well, another way of stating this sum is:

- The sum of all integers from 1<sup>2</sup> to (n-1)<sup>2</sup>, plus n<sup>2</sup>

That first step is usually the hardest because it's the most "obvious". For example, we know that "a + b + c" is the same as "a + b", plus "c", but we have to take a leap of faith of sorts and state it that way to get it into a recursive form.

So, now we have to take care of the special base case, 0:

- When n is 0, the sum is 0.

So let's let `recurvMath(n)` be the sum of all integers from 1<sup>2</sup> to n<sup>2</sup>. Then, the above directly translates to:

- recurvMath(n) = recurvMath(n-1) + n<sup>2</sup>
- recurvMath(0) = 0

And this is pretty easy to implement:

```
public int recurvMath(int n){    
    System.out.println("N:" +n);
    if(n == 0){
        return 0; 
    } else {
        return recurvMath(n-1) + (n * n);
    }
}
```

Note I've chosen to go with `n * n` instead of `Math.pow()`. This is because `Math.pow()` operates on `double`, not on `int`.

By the way, you may also want to protect yourself against a user entering negative numbers as input, which could get you stuck. You could use `if (n <= 0)` instead of `if (n == 0)`, or check for a negative input and throw e.g. `IllegalArgumentException`, or even use `Math.abs()` appropriately and give it the ability to work with negative numbers.

---

Also, for completeness, let's take a look at the problem in your original code. Your problem line is:

```
recurvMath((int) ((int) n+Math.pow(n, 2)))
```

Let's trace through this in our head. One of your `int` casts is unnecessary but ignoring that, when `n == 3` this is `recurvMath(3 + Math.pow(3, 2))` which is `recurvMath(12)`. Your number gets larger each time. You never hit your base cases of 1 or 0, and so you never terminate. Eventually you either get an integer overflow with incorrect results, or a stack overflow.

Comment: Don't even need of `else` in you solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab9Math {

int count = 0;
static double squareSum = 0;


public static void main(String[] args){

    int n = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the value you want n to be: ");
    n = scan.nextInt();

    Lab9Math est = new Lab9Math();
    squareSum = est.recurvMath(n);
    System.out.println("Sum is: "+squareSum);
}

public int recurvMath(int n){

    System.out.println("N:" +n);
        if(n == 1){
            return 1; 
        }//end if
        // More simplified solution
        return recurvMath(n-1) + (int) Math.pow(n, 2); // Here is made changes

    }//end method       
}//end class
```

Comment: I got that far, but i can't seem to understand why i have to send in (n-1) as an argument instead of n.

Comment: Otherwise stack will overflow. Means that your base condition will never hit. Or in other words you are call a function again and again infinite times. If you found my answer helpful then please mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

instead of saying:

```
return (recurvMath((int) ((int) n+Math.pow(n, 2))));
```

i instead said:

```
return (int) ((Math.pow(n, 2)+recurvMath(n-1)));
```